# How do i provide a fallback URL or file for a uhttpd server?

Tags: http, webserver, embedded-linux, openwrt

I am running a uhttpd server using the following command

> uhttpd -p 8000 -h /www -u /api -a b -X d &

in my /www folder, I have placed my UI files with an index.html
So, the index.html is served on < ip >:8000

But, my index.html redirects to another page like /m/login.html which, when refreshed will not be found.

I need to add a fallback so that if the page is refreshed, it redirects to /index.html

I tried using

> uhttpd -p 8000 -h /www -E /www/index.html -u /api -a b -X d &

but that did not work. Am I using the -E option wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The help output of `uhttpd` tells us this about the `-E` flag:

```
    -E string       Use given virtual URL as 404 error handler
```

"Virtual URL" implies that you should use a URL path, e.g. `/` or `/index.html` instead of a filesystem path.